# React Native draggable component - allow dragging until certain x value is reached, then animate out?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

Alright, here's what Im trying to do in RN- I want to be able to drag these Card components on the x axis. When the card hits an x value threshold on the right or left side, draggability is taken away and the card animates the far left or far right static position.

[image]

I have the "outro" scale down and translate animation working:

```
let animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 1000,
          easing: Easing.out(Easing.exp)
      }).start()
```

and styles

```
transform: [
            {
                translateX: animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [0, 120]
                })
            },
            {
                translateY: animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [0, 10]
                })
            },
            {
                scaleX: animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [1, 0.8]
                })
            },
            {
                scaleY: animatedValue.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 1],
                    outputRange: [1, 0.8]
                })
            }
        ]
```

and the dragging code I plan to take from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5-6xVmcIUA

I just dont know how to trigger this animation when a certain x value is reached on either end (reference the diagram), or whether this is the most efficient way of going about this.

Ive looked into card swipe libraries and packages, but Id like to do this as minimally as possible.

How can I trigger an animation/disallow dragging when a certain x limit is reached?

Answer (score 0):

you can use PanResponder to detect position of Element. Here you can see details with examples: [React Native PanResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder)